# how to integrate chained payment with hybrid android app with IONIC framework

Tags: android, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am New to this hybrid application.

 i don't know how to integrate **chained payment with hybrid android & IOS app** with IONIC framework in windows platform. 

is there any plugin available. tell me the steps?.

Answer (score 0):

there is no plugin.
You have to make rest request to the paypal api https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api

Answer (score 0):

Essentially this isn't an Ionic issue, Ionic is merely a framework to write applications in AngularJS, however, there is a [PayPal plugin for Cordova](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin) that may help. I haven't personally tried it.

Another option is to use an [AngularJS module for Stripe](https://github.com/laurihy/angular-payments).